# Visualizing a 3D array

Tags: matlab, 3d, visualization, matlab-figure

So this is what I am trying to do.
I have an image, with 181 columns and 4725 rows.
I take the 1st column, replicate it 180 more times to create a new image.
I take the 2nd column, replicate it 180 more times to create again a new image.
This procedure continues until I finish all columns. At the end I obtain as many new images as columns (181).
I need to visualize some slices of all this set. I tried with slice/sliceomatic but I am just blocked and don't know what to do and how to do it.

I load the image as a 2D matrix Z. The values of xslice/yslice/zslice are just given to have a try.
I tried doing this by taking a 3x3x3 matrix (instead of the whole image with the 4725 rows) to save some time and try to understand how the code should be done, but I couldn't get it.
Anyone can help? Thanks in advance. The code and image are below.

```
close all
clear all
clc
load('matlab.mat')

     for y=1:1:182
B{y}=repmat(Z(:,y),1,182);
v{y}=B{y};
cat(3,v(:));
       end

 [x,y,z]=meshgrid(1:1:4725,1:1:182,1:1:182);
 v=????
 xslice = [1500];   
 yslice = [75];
 zslice = 75;
 slice(x,y,z,v,xslice,yslice,zslice)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6jg2.png)

Comment: Your loop is identical to `repmat(reshape(Z,size(Z,1),1,size(Z,2)),1,182,1)`.

Comment: It seems to work! I tried this for a 3x3 matrix and it worked but for the case with my image it is blocking each time. I sent the code to a friend with everything, but his matlab blocks as well...because there will be 182x4725x182 values...any idea what to do in this case? I guess I will have to ask for a better computer since I am running it on my PC.

Comment: Indeed, that's a 1.2 Gb array. If you don't have enough memory you'll have to do the processing/visualizing in chunks.

Comment: I have 8GB of memory available actually, but I don't know why it blocks...

Comment: You're on 32-bit Windows maybe?

Comment: 64 actually :S I will just run an antivirus scan and clean few stuff to see if that will help first. Thank you so much btw for the above line of code!